# Laravel - making vue work with other plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js

I have a project where I would like to use this [theme](http://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-dashboard/dashboard.html). I just downloaded it and put its scripts into `resources/assets/js` directory. This is how I am calling all the scripts, after I run gulp, that I need for the page:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script
type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/material/material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/material/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script>$.material.init()</script>

<!--  Checkbox, Radio & Switch Plugins -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js"></script>

<!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

<!-- Paper Dashboard Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
<script src="/js/paper-dashboard.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.notify({
          icon: 'ti-gift',
          message: "Welcome to <b>Paper Dashboard</b> - a beautiful Bootstrap freebie for your next project."

        },{
            type: 'success',
            timer: 4000
        });

  });
</script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

But then I can't get bootstrap notify or tooltip work, if I remove app.js I get it working again, but then vue components are not working.

This is the app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

var VueResource = require('vue-resource');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the body of the page. From here, you may begin adding components to
 * the application, or feel free to tweak this setup for your needs.
 */

Vue.component('video-upload', require('./components/VideoUpload.vue'));
Vue.component('video-player', require('./components/VideoPlayer.vue'));
Vue.component('video-voting', require('./components/VideoVoting.vue'));

Vue.use(VueResource);

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: window.videoApp
});
```

And this is the gulpfile:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/css', 'public/css');

    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

**Update**

I have required as craig_h suggested at the bottom of my bootstrap.js files like this:

```
require('./bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js');
require('./bootstrap-notify.js');
require('./paper-dashboard.js');
```

But I get an error:

> paper-dashboard.js?16eb:26Uncaught ReferenceError: lbd is not
>   defined(…)

This is the script paper-dashboard.js:

```
var fixedTop = false;

var navbar_initialized = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    window_width = $(window).width();

    // Init navigation toggle for small screens
    if(window_width <= 991){
        lbd.initRightMenu();
    }

    //  Activate the tooltips
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();

});

// activate collapse right menu when the windows is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 991){
        lbd.initRightMenu();
    }
});

lbd = {
    misc:{
        navbar_menu_visible: 0
    },

    initRightMenu: function(){
         if(!navbar_initialized){
            $off_canvas_sidebar = $('nav').find('.navbar-collapse').first().clone(true);

            $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
            sidebar_bg_color = $sidebar.data('background-color');
            sidebar_active_color = $sidebar.data('active-color');

            $logo = $sidebar.find('.logo').first();
            logo_content = $logo[0].outerHTML;

            ul_content = '';

            // set the bg color and active color from the default sidebar to the off canvas sidebar;
            $off_canvas_sidebar.attr('data-background-color',sidebar_bg_color);
            $off_canvas_sidebar.attr('data-active-color',sidebar_active_color);

            $off_canvas_sidebar.addClass('off-canvas-sidebar');

            //add the content from the regular header to the right menu
            $off_canvas_sidebar.children('ul').each(function(){
                content_buff = $(this).html();
                ul_content = ul_content + content_buff;
            });

            // add the content from the sidebar to the right menu
            content_buff = $sidebar.find('.nav').html();
            ul_content = ul_content + '<li class="divider"></li>'+ content_buff;

            ul_content = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' + ul_content + '</ul>';

            navbar_content = logo_content + ul_content;
            navbar_content = '<div class="sidebar-wrapper">' + navbar_content + '</div>';

            $off_canvas_sidebar.html(navbar_content);

            $('body').append($off_canvas_sidebar);

             $toggle = $('.navbar-toggle');

             $off_canvas_sidebar.find('a').removeClass('btn btn-round btn-default');
             $off_canvas_sidebar.find('button').removeClass('btn-round btn-fill btn-info btn-primary btn-success btn-danger btn-warning btn-neutral');
             $off_canvas_sidebar.find('button').addClass('btn-simple btn-block');

             $toggle.click(function (){
                if(lbd.misc.navbar_menu_visible == 1) {
                    $('html').removeClass('nav-open');
                    lbd.misc.navbar_menu_visible = 0;
                    $('#bodyClick').remove();
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        $toggle.removeClass('toggled');
                     }, 400);

                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $toggle.addClass('toggled');
                    }, 430);

                    div = '<div id="bodyClick"></div>';
                    $(div).appendTo("body").click(function() {
                        $('html').removeClass('nav-open');
                        lbd.misc.navbar_menu_visible = 0;
                        $('#bodyClick').remove();
                         setTimeout(function(){
                            $toggle.removeClass('toggled');
                         }, 400);
                    });

                    $('html').addClass('nav-open');
                    lbd.misc.navbar_menu_visible = 1;

                }
            });
            navbar_initialized = true;
        }

    }
}


// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

My apologizes if this is a begginers question, but I have not used webpack or browserify before so I don't know how to setup all of this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `webpack` I use `browserify` instead, but I think the problem is that you are using packages that rely on global variables, if you want to do that then you need to use an importer, see [shimming modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html)

However, you can usually just get away with requiring them in: `/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` like so:

`require('./bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js')`

`require('./bootstrap-notify.js')`

`require('./paper-dashboard.js')`

Then just running `gulp`

Comment: I have set it up like you suggested, but I am obviously doing something wrong, since the paper-dashboard is causing errors now. I have also updated my question with new info.

Comment: Javascript scoping is a pain, It looks like you may need to `shim` jQuery to get that functioning (https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html), but as I said I don't use `webpack` and have only briefly read up on how it works, so you may need someone with more `webpack` knowledge than me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this:

> paper-dashboard.js?16eb:26Uncaught ReferenceError: lbd is not
>   defined(…)

try edit `paper-dashboard.js` and define `lbd` to the global scope using `window` like this:

```js
...
window['lbd'] = {
    misc:{
        navbar_menu_visible: 0
    },
...
```